# XPath for complexType wrapper in element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

I have following element defined in XSD schema

```
<xs:element name="MainType">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="InnerType">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="OtherType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to write binding for OtherType, but I have problems with XPath. I wrote this XPath for addresing of OtherType.

```
//xs:element[@name='MainType']//xs:complexType//xs:element[@name='InnerType']//xs:complexType//xs:element[@name='OtherType']
```

I tried to skip complexType between elements in XPath, but it also doesn't work. JAXB plugin returns this error

```
om.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: XPath evaluation of ... results in empty target node
```

Comment: The innermost attribute you are looking for is `@ref='OtherType'` not @name?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this mistake.

Comment: Did this answer the question, i.e. can we close as a minor typo?

Comment: Als reconsider using `//`

Comment: The whole XPath expression seems pretty over-specific to me. Would `//xs:element[@ref='OtherType']` be enough or does it *really* have to be "*`xs:element[@ref='OtherType']`, only if descendant of `xs:element[@name='InnerType]`, only if descendant of `xs:element[@name='MainType']`, only if descendant of any node in the document"*?

Comment: You should post the correct XPath as an answer instead of as an update the question.  This will make it easier for people with this problem in the future to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right XPath:

```
//xs:element[@name='MainType']//xs:element[@name='InnerType//xs:element[@ref='OtherType']
```